# error "index.html:58 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).circleGraphic is not a function"

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a page from scratch and I have some issues making a circle graphic to work.

This is my html code:

```
 <div class="row fourth-section">
   <div class="trd-ev">
     <h2>Title</h2>
     <div class="row section-one">
       <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="circleGraphic1">
           <canvas id="c0.3753633318105867" width="246" height="246"></canvas>
         </div>
         <script type="text/javascript">
           window.onload = function () {$('.circleGraphic1').circleGraphic(); }
         </script>
       </div>
     </div>
  <div class="arrow bounce">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my css code:

```
.circleGraphic1 {
  color: transparent;
  height: 246px;
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

And this is the Console error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).circleGraphic is not a functionwindow.onload `@ index.html:58.

Can you help me with some advises?

Many thanks,

S.

Comment: Have you loaded jquery? and whatever jquery add-on gives you the .circleGraphic function you want to use?

Comment: You can look into http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVRGva

Comment: @JaromandaX, here is the <head> tag: http://codepen.io/Sandrusha/pen/ORVyRo

Can you check it for me, please?

Comment: @Gowtham, thank you so much. Those examples are pretty awesome ;)

Comment: so you aren't loading any library for .circleGraphic

Comment: @JaromandaX, just this thing: 
<script type="text/javascript">
                window.onload = function () { $('.circleGraphic1').circleGraphic(); }
</script>

Comment: @JaromandaX, I see now where the problem is. I'll make several tries and if I can't make it to work, I'll come back here and ask for help.

Comment: @JaromandaX, here it works: http://codepen.io/Sandrusha/pen/ORVyRo

But on my webpage I have the same error: "index.html:60 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).circleGraphic is not a function" and I can't see the circle into my page. But on codepen it works. Where is the problem?

Many thanks again!

Comment: I've solved this issue! I've just moved:  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/circleGraphic.js" ></script> after </body> and it works now.

Comment: add this code on your `<head>`: `<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>`